# What is the C++ code for this exercise?

Tags: c++

I want the C++ code for this exercise especially the part of shifting the elements of the array.

**Exercise:**

Write a function, deleteChar, which deletes any occurrence in the first argument, a, of the single character which is the second argument, c.

Assume the prototype is

void deleteChar(char a[], char c);

**Sample Output:**

**Type in a string:** The lord of the ring is cool

**Enter a letter to delete:** o

**The string after deleting the character 'o':** the lrd f the ring is cl

---

This is my code for the function part:

```
void deleteChar(char a[], char c)
{
int x= strlen(a);
for(int i=x-1;i>=0;i--)
{if(a[i]==c)
   {a[i]=' ';}
}
for(int i=x-1;i>=0;i--)
{
if(a[i]==' ')
a[i]=a[i+1];
a[i+1]=' ';


}
cout<<a;

}
```

Comment: What improvement did you make so far?

Comment: `I want the C++ code for this exercise` I want people either to learn programming or to quit programming. Seriously, at least try something.

Comment: I wrote this code but it has something wrong in the shifting method ;/

Comment: Please edit your question with the code.  As you can see, the code is incomprehensible when pasted as a comment.

Comment: @ReemAlHawaj if you want answers from here, it's recommended that you show some effort. I suggest you edit your question to show the part of your code you have problems with.

Comment: This would be soooo much easier if you can use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` instead of the array.  By the way, the assignment is bad because every array should be passed with the capacity as an additional parameter.

Comment: I recommend you reformat your code, use spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

My brain is fried, so I won't give you the code for shifting.

I'll be nice and supply you with a methodology.

A "shift" is where you replace the value in a previous slot with the value in the next slot:

```
  0   1   2   3    
+---+---+---+---+  
| c | o | a | l |  
+---+---+---+---+
```

To shift delete the 'o' at position 1, the letter's following, in positions 2 and 3, are copied over:

```
  0   1   2   3    
+---+---+---+---+  
| c | a | a | l |  
+---+---+---+---+  
      ^   |  
      +---+  

  0   1   2   3    
+---+---+---+---+  
| c | a | l | l |  
+---+---+---+---+  
          ^   |  
          +---+
```

Manually, the steps are:

```
  a[1] = a[2];
  a[2] = a[3];
```

With paper and a writing instrument, write down the steps for deleting the letter 'c' in the above array.

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Yes, I see.
I actually did this on a paper and tried a lot of methods before I post my problem.
But thank you for your helps and for the pattern it made the idea clearer and i got an idea, I will try it.

Thank you again :)

Comment: Once you know the algorithm, look up functions in the library and see if any can be helpful.  Some functions that come to mind are `memcpy` and `memmove`.